# gitlab transfer to new server without creating backup

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

my current server's OS has been corrupted, and the gitlab commands not work. so I can not create backup with  gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create command. is there any other way to transfer gitlab data to new server
I'm using gitlab 10.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to :

- backup the postgres database [manually](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html) (checkout `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` for the credentials if needed)
- backup the git data (I think it's located in `/mnt/git-data` by default, checkout `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` for the specific location)
- backup `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
- backup `/etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json`

Then starts a new fresh Gitlab CE instance with the same version as the previous one (and same type of installation as before eg Omnibus/from source/docker/etc...):

- copy `gitlab.rb` and `gitlab-secrets.json` in `/etc/gitlab`
- copy the backuped git data into `/mnt/git-data` (if it was the correct location in `gitlab.rb`)
- [restore the postgres database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html)

Then perform: `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and see how it goes

Note that all the above may not apply to your version 10.7.1 which is very old (04-2018)